# How to tell Django not to escape html from request.POST data?

Tags: django

Im using ajax to get svg graphs and django escapes all html signs...how can i prevent this and get the raw data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the code that returns/outputs your svg graphs?

Comment: thanks for asking...when i print it its already converted into html like this:  style=""&gt;
&lt;/path&gt;
&lt;/g&gt;
&lt;/g&gt;
&lt;/svg&gt;

Comment: I mean, you say that you use ajax. So if you just use ajax, then django doesnt do anything on client side.

What I am interested is what is your server code that outputs your ajax response.

Comment: you are right...ajax has already the escaped code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **your view** is outputting your **svg**, it escapes it if you serve it as a **string**.
But **svg equals xml** which means that you could **serve your svg using django templating**.

Comment: If you make ajax calls from your page, your page is already served.
So your page's view should have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that django escapes the HTML on its way out in the response, then it's simple - wrap any HTML strings in `mark_safe` (from `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`)

Like this:

```
def myview(request):
    html_data = "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    return render(request, "template.html", {"html": mark_safe(html_data)})
```

Comment: thanks...but its the other way round: ajax sends it and the view is taking it as escaped format...

Comment: Your "view" shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: @toninoj I agree - it sounded to me like the OP misspoke when describing the problem, since the only escaping I could think of would be in view code. Sounds like that wasn't the problem, though.

Comment: ... unless the 'ajax' response is served by a django view :) In any case, this could still be resolved with javascript I believe.